# CSS doesn't work the same way on mobile device, as it works on desktop

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

this is my first serious massive problem which I couldn't solve by googling (what I am doing so even when it's taking me the whole day to solve the problem). As it's been mentioned in the subject, looks like the CSS is not loaded on mobile device, but it works fine on desktop (localhost XAMPP). While I am working on the project using desktop all of the buttons on slick-slider looks properly as it's been set by me. While I am checking the page on the live-server on mobile device, the buttons to use sliders looks like default one (in reality they are really small and outside the slider, visually is not acceptable even it's difficulty to click on them).

Head section already has meta for mobile devices, and also @import url() for mobile devices has been set (but it doesn't make any change):

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("slick/slick.css");</style>
  <style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("slick/slick-theme.css");</style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="$cssAddress">
  <title>$titleText</title> 
</head>
```

Slider section of html:

```
<div class="slickSlider">
  <div><img src="productImg/BK1.jpg" alt="First Slide" width="100%"></div>
  <div><img src="productImg/BK2.jpg" alt="Second Slide" width="100%"></div>
  <div><img src="productImg/BK3.jpg" alt="Third Slide" width="100%"></div>
</div>
```

All of the scripts are inside the body

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.slickSlider').slick({
          dots: true,
          swipeToSlide: true,
          dotsClass: 'slick-dots',
          prevArrow: "<img class='a-left control-c prev slick-prev' src='img/arrowLeft.png'>",
          nextArrow: "<img class='a-right control-c next slick-next' src='img/arrowRight.png'>"
        });
      });
    </script>
<script src='js/product_page.js'></script>
<script src='js/burger.js'></script>
```

So far I have tried so many different carousels (e.g. bootstrap 4 carousel) which one also worked correctly on desktop(), also created one, on my own, but I gave up on implementing swiping on mobile.

I also tried to implement CSS in mobile media query, but without any significant results.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .slick-prev {
    left: 100px;
    background: red; /*to notice it, is white*/
}
.slick-next {
    right: 100px;
    background: red; /*to notice it, is white*/
}
}
```

Also I am giving a link to the website I am currently working on as this might give a clue:
Please don't blame me for entire appearance as it is only right now designed for nice development purpose, not the final product and only partially designed for desktop. I was working mainly on website functionality (PHP and SQL).

PS. Slider is located under knitwear in navigation and then you need to choose first available product to get to the product_page.php

[ManhattanStyleBoutique](http://kubiakstudio.com/ManhattanStyleBoutique/index.php)

Thank you for reading post, and hopefully I will find some help as problem with my site I have got for almost 2 weeks right now. Apologise for my english syntax.

Kind regards

Pat

Comment: how much viewport pixels does the mobile device have you using? Is it a tablet? 768px is tablet side. Most smartphone have a max width of 480px viewport in landscape mode. Remind that for mobile devices 1px does not equal 1px. There is a difference between Vieport Pixel andHardware pixels.

Comment: You havent yet implemented the slider on the link that you provided.

Comment: Something else to keep in mind is caching. With testing on actual mobiles (instead of a desktop browsers devtools mobile modes), it can be a hassle at times to fight (like SafarI) when its cached a css file contents, despite having just changed its contents. Changing the actual css filename tends to make it recache, but that can be a pain to deal with (and just appending `?_timestamp` doesnt work in some Safari versions). If you can manage the devtools on a mobile (Tablet), then you can force disable cache. However on phones... ugh.

Comment: @tacoshy mobile device is iPhone X with a viewport of 375x812. I tried to change media query to 480px, but it seems it might not work right now ... as IncredibleHat mentioned it

Comment: @IncredibleHat the problem still appears even after few hours and fully deleting and pasting again entire website to the live server and after clearing web history and the rest on mobile. I actually was thinking that might be cache problem on the server side so I contacted with Bluehost, but they told me that my site is not mobile friendly.

Comment: @Arbin Shrestha it is not a direct link to the product page with slider as it is not working why values from previous php are passed to the php. Post has been edited with the solution of how to go deeper to the slider (just 3 more clicks ;))